# Helm + Org-Goto + Narrow to Subtree + Follow Mode

Tags: org-mode, helm

I am using `org-goto` with `helm` and my init file has the following config:

```
  (setq org-goto-interface 'outline-path-completion)
  (setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
```

This works fine but I would love to make a few adjustments:

1. Activate follow mode, so the main buffer displays the contents of each heading, as I navigate through the list in helm.
2. Narrow main buffer to a subtree, once I make my selection.

Screenshot of my current setup, while running `org-goto`.

[image]

Any ideas?